# Calling JS function from JSP tag

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm trying to call a JS function, `escapeHtml(unsafe)`, in this tag

file.jsp

```
<form:form modelAttribute="messagingForm" id="messagingForm" action="${messagingSendUrl}">
[...]
    <foo:bar string="${escapeHtml(messagingForm.text)}" substring="${searchstring}"/>
[...]
</form:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
        [...]
    }
</script>
```

I get this error: The function escapeHtml must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified.

I have tried:

```
<foo:bar string="<spring:message code="escapeHtml('${messagingForm.text}')"/>" substring="${searchstring}"/>
```

I get this error: file.jsp(xx,17) equal symbol expected
and: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I tried:

```
<foo:bar string="<spring:message code='escapeHtml("${messagingForm.text}")'/>" substring="${searchstring}"/>
```

I get this error: file.jsp(xx,xx) Unterminated &lt;foo:bar tag

====EDIT for Anthony Grist====

Well, I can do this:

```
<c:when test="${reply}">
    <button id="btn_msg_reply_dispatcher"
        title="<spring:message
          code="messaging.alt.replyvehicleanddispatcher"
          argumentSeparator=";"
          arguments="${vehicleName};${sender}" />"
        onclick="replyVehicleAndDispatcher(${vehicleInformationId}, ${sid}, '${sender}'); return false;">
    </button>
</c:when>
[...]
<script type="text/javascript">
    function replyVehicleAndDispatcher(vehicleInformationId, userId, userName) {
        [...]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: JSP is a server-side language, JavaScript is a client-side language. You can't execute a JavaScript function as part of your JSP tag because it doesn't exist yet. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: See edit for comment.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. It's totally irrelevant though, because all you're doing is writing HTML that defines a JavaScript event handler; on the server-side that does absolutely nothing, it's just text. It's only when it's been parsed by the user's browser that it sets up the event handler, and it's only when the user clicks on it that the function is called. You can't call a JavaScript function to set the content of an attribute on a JSP tag, which seems to be what you're trying to do. You also can't use a JSP tag to set the content of an attribute on another JSP tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="msg"><spring:message code="${messagingForm.text}" htmlEscape="true"/></c:set>
<foo:bar substring="${searchstring}" string="${msg}" />
```

Comment: what is the value of `substring` and `string` in console?

Comment: substring='Sven Svensson'
string='This is Mumford & Sons;'

Comment: aren't those the values you wanted? you are able to assign values to both string and substring, then which part isn't working? any error msg displayed?

Comment: Ok, those are SUPPOSED to be the values in the console. Now there're no values, since the program crashes with above mentioned errors.

Comment: I couldn't build the code value with the '+'. This is what I did:
<c:set var="msg"><spring:message code="escapeHtml('${messagingForm.text}')"/></c:set>
<foo:bar substring="${searchstring}" string="${msg}" />.  


This doesn't call the function, though. It outputs:
escapeHtml('This is Mumford ')

Comment: use the attribute `htmlEscape="true"` in `spring:message`, check my update in answer, try both `true` and `false`

Comment: Now, that wouldn't call my custom function, would it?

Comment: hmmm, have you btw tried `htmlEscape=true`?is it avoiding the html characters?

Comment: communicating between client and server side is not possible, why not write an equivalent to your custom function at the backend in java and return the appropriate value to the JSP?